# While loop repeating in script

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

max=30 
grep-E ^[^:]+:[^\!*] /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{print $1 ":" $7} | while read user days
do 
 if [[ "$days" -gt 30 ]] || [[ "$days" == "" ]]
then
    echo Non-compliance: Yes
    grep $user /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,7
fi 
done
```

Expected output: 
Non Compliance: Yes 
root:
 student:50

My output: 
 Non Compliance: Yes 
root
 Non Compliance: Yes
 student:50

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to prevent multiple printing

```
if [ "$once" != 1 ] ; then
    echo Non-compliance: Yes
    once=1
fi
grep $user /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,7
```